# How to confirm that a wireless router is working properly?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

My router (Netgear dgn2000) LAN works, but not my wireless. The wireless light shows up when first booting and sometimes when I reset, at least for a few seconds, then dies out. I had my Kindle out and it seemed to work for a few seconds (downloaded a book and part of another) but then stopped.

Is there anyway to test if the wireless part physically works? All the settings I can think that are supposed to be checked are checked (enable wireless access point, broadcast ssid, the router statistics says it has been up for 30 minutes).  Multiple wireless devices can't see the network when scanning. The network password is correct (same case, no zero/oh issues).

As I mentioned I reset a few times, but with the buttons and by unplugging.

router status reads:
WLAN1
Name (SSID) ShackShack
Wireless AP Enabled
Broadcast Name  Enabled

Comment: wow. this is the third WiFi/Router issue in a row. 2012 must be early.

Comment: To check if the wireless router is transmitting its SID, run inSSIDer (from www.metageek.net) on a PC/laptop with a working wifi adapter.  You'll be able to check if your unit is using an already congested channel.

Comment: So I ran it and the wireless seemed to be running even though I couldn't connect. But after I hit the reset button, the wireless stopped working at all: no light, no signal. Time for a new modem after only a year :(